# Special symbols in legend in R

Tags: r, legend, symbols

I want to write special symbols in the legend in a plot, like 5<# of events<=20. So far I've tried multiple codes but didn't work.

I don't know why this doesn't work
`bquote(5<~"# of events"~<=20)`

I finally made this work (in a clumsy way):
`legend_txt <- c(bquote('5 < # of counties' <= 20), bquote('20 < # of counties' <= 60), bquote('60 < # of counties' <= 100), bquote('# of counties' >= 100))`
But as you can see, the < is different from <= in the legend. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

example code:

```
x = c(0, 5, 10, 15)
y = c(2.2, 3.8, 4.6, 7.6)
z = c(4.5, 6.8, 9.3, 10.5)
plot(x, y, type="l", lwd=2, col=1, ylim=c(0, 12))
lines(x,z, lwd=2, col=2)
legend_txt <- c(bquote('5 < # events' <= 20),bquote('20 < # of events' <= 60))
legend('topright', legend = legend_txt, col = 1:2, lty = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this is what you are looking for. Put two tildes before the 5 and the legends align.

```r
x = c(0, 5, 10, 15)
y = c(2.2, 3.8, 4.6, 7.6)
z = c(4.5, 6.8, 9.3, 10.5)
plot(x, y, type="l", lwd=2, col=1, ylim=c(0, 12))
lines(x,z, lwd=2, col=2)
legend_txt <- c(bquote(~~5 <~ '# of events' <= 20),
                bquote(20 <~ '# of events' <= 60))
legend('topright', legend = legend_txt, col = 1:2, lty = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>